# How to keep a mysql connection alive with libodbc.so

Tags: mysql, odbc

I use SQLConnect() to connect mysql, but mysql terminates the connection after some time, my question is:

1. is there any api to check if the connection is still alive?
   I went through similar questions and found that "select 1" or "do 1" can do, if there is no api, maybe I can try...
2. I'd like to keep the connection alive all the time,
   2.1 what options in configuration files can be set to keep connection alive?
   2.2 how to keep connection alive with API?

Thanks much.
-zhen

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me answer my own questions:

Now I still failed to find any api to detect if the connection is still alive, so issuing do 1 or select 1 may be the best way to keep the connection alive all the time;

No need to keep a connection alive all the time, we can create a new connect once we want to access the database, and disconnect after we finished;